# Loading frozen tf model - no placeholder tensor value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tried to freeze my Tensorflow graph and restore it, but when I try and run prediction, I get the error:

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'DQNetwork/actions' with dtype float and shape [?,10]
```

My restoration code is:

```
sess = tf.Session()
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

with graph.as_default():
    with sess.as_default():
        GRAPH_PB_PATH = "./frozentensorflowModel.pb"
        with gfile.FastGFile(GRAPH_PB_PATH,'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

        x_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name("DQNetwork/inputs:0")
        op_to_restore = graph.get_tensor_by_name("DQNetwork/actions:0")

        new_state(cards.copy())
        state = game_state.state

        feed_dict={x_tensor: state.reshape((1, *state.shape))}
        opt = []
        opt = sess.run(op_to_restore, feed_dict) # Error throws
        predictions = np.argmax(opt, 1)
```

I defined my `DQNetwork` inputs like so:

```
DQNetwork.inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, state_size], name="inputs") 
DQNetwork.actions = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, action_size], name="actions")
```

More info:

```
>>>op_to_restore
<tf.Tensor 'DQNetwork/actions:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32>
>>>op_to_restore.op
<tf.Operation 'DQNetwork/actions' type=Placeholder>
```

Training line:

```
results = sess.run(DQNetwork.output, feed_dict = {DQNetwork.inputs: input_batch})
```

Comment: Is it tensor and not operation `"DQNetwork/actions:0"` ?

Comment: What was this during training: op_to_restore? Can you show me the line of your training?

Comment: Updated various parts. Thanks for helping!

Comment: You see this `<tf.Operation 'DQNetwork/actions' type=Placeholder>` its in your question. The value is not Tensor. Instead its operation

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: Why not try this: `op_to_restore = graph.get_tensor_by_name("actions:0")`

Comment: Is it working for ya?

Comment: I’m not at my pc currently, il let you know in about an hour. Will I have to do what you suggested for the input tensor too?

Comment: You can try it out. I guess it will work.

Comment: I get this error: `"The name 'actions:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'actions', does not exist in the graph."
`

Comment: Try this `graph.get_operation_by_name("DQNetwork/actions")` May help.

Comment: I get the error: `The name 'DQNetwork/inputs' refers to an Operation, not a Tensor. Tensor names must be of the form "<op_name>:<output_index>"`

Comment: I guess I have mentioned it only for the `DQNetwork/actions:0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194114/discussion-between-amazing-things-around-you-and-harry-stuart).

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
sess = tf.Session()
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

with graph.as_default():
    with sess.as_default():
        GRAPH_PB_PATH = "./frozentensorflowModel.pb"
        with gfile.FastGFile(GRAPH_PB_PATH,'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

        x_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name("DQNetwork/inputs:0")
        op_to_restore = graph.get_operation_by_name("DQNetwork/actions")

        new_state(cards.copy())
        state = game_state.state

        feed_dict={x_tensor: state.reshape((1, *state.shape))}
        opt = []
        opt = sess.run(op_to_restore, feed_dict) # Error throws
        predictions = np.argmax(opt, 1)
```

This is what I was suggesting.

I got the point:

```
feed_dict={x_tensor: state.reshape((1, *state.shape))}
```

Instead of `sess.run(op_to_restore, feed_dict)` try `op_to_restore.eval(feeddict)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem. I am getting the same original error